# audio upload in cakephp2.4

Tags: cakephp, audio, file-upload, cakephp-2.4

I want to upload audio files (type `mp3`,`acc`,`wav`) I am using `cakephp 2.4.1 stable` and `php5 stable`. I have tried `mime_content_type`,`finfo_file` to check if uploaded file is audio file with either mp3,acc or wav type. But I get this

```
`error mime_content_type(059.piya basanti re... [piya basanti][2000].mp3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [APP/Controller/AdminController.php, line 86]`
```

My app dir and webroot dir are permited with 0777.

Here is my **view.ctp** code :

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Homepage',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('audio_1',array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Submit');
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

my **Controller** code

```
    public function saveaudio() {
            if($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->loadModel('Homepage');
//this is line 86//   $file = mime_content_type($this->request->data['Homepage']['audio_1']['name']);
                 pr($file);exit;
              }
```

and here is my data

```
Array
(
    [Homepage] => Array
        (
            [audio_1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 059.piya basanti re... [piya basanti][2000].mp3
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 1
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

My question is :

1. How I can check type of file? First I want to check its mime type then I want to save it
2. Why I am not getting tmp_name for uploaded file?
3. Why I am getting error for mime_content_type?

Can anyone explain me? It would be helpfull to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the data, the upload was discarded as there's an error. `1` equals `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`, and the cause for this is:

> The uploaded file exceeds the [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in `php.ini`.

See http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php

So you have to increase that value, and most probably also [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size), see http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php for more information.

And once the uploading works, you'll have to use the correct keys, it's `audio_1`, not `audio_`, also you'll then have to use `tmp_name`, ie this:

```
$this->request->data['Homepage']['audio_']['name']
```

should be this

```
$this->request->data['Homepage']['audio_1']['tmp_name']
```

On a side note, [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/function.mime-content-type.php) is deprecated in favour of the [`Fileinfo`](http://php.net/manual/ref.fileinfo.php) extension.